# Subset rows of data that contain a specific string over several columns

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset and I need to subset my dataset to keep only those IDs that contain the word "Paracetamol" across any of the medication columns ex.medication1, medication2, medication3, etc. until medication50.

Please help <3

```
df <- data.frame(id = paste0("ID",1:10),
             Medication1= c("paracetamol", "ibuprofen", "opiate", "sertraline"),
             Medication2= c("Lipitor", "ketamine", "zoloft", "xanax"),
             Medication3= c("ibuprofen", "paracetamol", "Zocor", "Zestril"),
             other= LETTERS[1:10])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution using [dplyr commands](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id = paste0("ID",1:4),
                 Medication1= c("paracetamol", "ibuprofen", "opiate", "sertraline"),
                 Medication2= c("Lipitor", "ketamine", "zoloft", "xanax"),
                 Medication3= c("ibuprofen", "paracetamol", "Zocor", "Zestril"),
                 other= c(LETTERS[1:3], "paracetamol"))
df
#>    id Medication1 Medication2 Medication3       other
#> 1 ID1 paracetamol     Lipitor   ibuprofen           A
#> 2 ID2   ibuprofen    ketamine paracetamol           B
#> 3 ID3      opiate      zoloft       Zocor           C
#> 4 ID4  sertraline       xanax     Zestril paracetamol

# only detect "paracetamol" in "Medication" columns
df %>%
  filter(if_any(.cols = starts_with("Medication"),
                .fns = ~grepl("paracetamol", .x)))
#>    id Medication1 Medication2 Medication3 other
#> 1 ID1 paracetamol     Lipitor   ibuprofen     A
#> 2 ID2   ibuprofen    ketamine paracetamol     B
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To get rows with "paracetamol" and "Paracetamol" you can use `ignore.case = TRUE`:

```r
df %>%
  filter(if_any(.cols = starts_with("Medication"),
                .fns = ~grepl("paracetamol", .x, ignore.case = TRUE)))
#>    id Medication1 Medication2 Medication3 other
#> 1 ID1 paracetamol     Lipitor   ibuprofen     A
#> 2 ID2   ibuprofen    ketamine paracetamol     B
```

---

If you want rows with the same active ingredient but different names:

```r
df %>%
  filter(if_any(.cols = starts_with("Medication"),
                .fns = ~grepl("paracetamol|Tylenol", .x, ignore.case = TRUE)))
#>    id Medication1 Medication2 Medication3 other
#> 1 ID1 paracetamol     Lipitor   ibuprofen     A
#> 2 ID2   ibuprofen    ketamine paracetamol     B
```

---

If you have ids spanning multiple rows (e.g. ID1) it gets more complicated, but one option would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- data.frame(id = paste0("ID",c(1,2,1,3)),
                 Medication1= c("paracetamol", "ibuprofen", "opiate", "sertraline"),
                 Medication2= c("Lipitor", "ketamine", "zoloft", "xanax"),
                 Medication3= c("ibuprofen", "paracetamol", "Zocor", "Zestril"),
                 other= c(LETTERS[1:3], "paracetamol"))
df2
#>    id Medication1 Medication2 Medication3       other
#> 1 ID1 paracetamol     Lipitor   ibuprofen           A
#> 2 ID2   ibuprofen    ketamine paracetamol           B
#> 3 ID1      opiate      zoloft       Zocor           C
#> 4 ID3  sertraline       xanax     Zestril paracetamol

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Medication"),
               names_to = "medications") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(any(value == "paracetamol")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = medications)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id    other Medication1 Medication2 Medication3
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1 ID1   A     paracetamol Lipitor     ibuprofen  
#> 2 ID2   B     ibuprofen   ketamine    paracetamol
#> 3 ID1   C     opiate      zoloft      Zocor
```

Answer (score 2):

In R you can check the entire data frame on equality with the word "paracetamol" which gives you a boolean matrix. Since `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`, you can calculate `rowSums`; and obviously you want to subset where they are greater than zero.

```
df[rowSums(df == 'paracetamol') > 0, ]
#    id Medication1 Medication2 Medication3 other
# 1 ID1 paracetamol     Lipitor   ibuprofen     A
# 2 ID2   ibuprofen    ketamine paracetamol     B
```

If you have `NA` in your data, use `rowSums(., na.rm=TRUE)`.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"), Medication1 = c("paracetamol", 
"ibuprofen", "opiate", "sertraline"), Medication2 = c("Lipitor", 
"ketamine", "zoloft", "xanax"), Medication3 = c("ibuprofen", 
"paracetamol", "Zocor", "Zestril"), other = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```